# select from a result

Tags: mysql, select

There are two tables

```
tracks(track_id,track_title)
track_rank(track_id,track_date_entered,track_position)
```

The following query gives me a list of songs with number of repetitions

```
SELECT
  tracks.track_title,
  track_rank.track_id,
  COUNT(track_rank.track_id) AS number_of_repetitions 
FROM
  tracks,
  track_rank 
WHERE
  track_rank.track_position = 1 
  AND track_rank.track_date_entered BETWEEN '1970-01-01' AND '1972-12-31' 
  AND tracks.track_id = track_rank.track_id 
GROUP BY
  track_rank.track_id 
ORDER BY
  number_of_repetitions DESC;
```

Can anyone please help me how to select only the tracks from the above result with highest number of repetitions after executing the above query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query that should get the tracks that have the highest number of repetitions for the filter conditions that you specify. This will also get you multiple tracks that have the same high no. of repetitions.

```
     SELECT tracks.track_title,track_rank.track_id , COUNT(track_rank.track_id) AS number_of_repetitions FROM tracks,track_rank 
       where tracks.track_id=track_rank.track_id
       WHERE track_rank.track_position = 1 
       AND track_rank.track_date_entered BETWEEN '1970-01-01' AND '1972-12-31' AND 
    tracks.track_id = track_rank.track_id 
    GROUP BY track_rank.track_id 
    having COUNT(track_rank.track_id) =
    (
       SELECT 
    COUNT(track_rank.track_id) AS number_of_repetitions 
    FROM tracks,track_rank 
    where tracks.track_id=track_rank.track_id
    WHERE track_rank.track_position = 1 
    AND track_rank.track_date_entered BETWEEN '1970-01-01' AND '1972-12-31' 
    AND tracks.track_id = track_rank.track_id 
    GROUP BY track_rank.track_id 
    order by number_of_repetitions  desc
    limit 1
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

For `AGGREGATE` functions `ORDER BY` use:

```
 ORDER BY COUNT(track_rank.track_id) DESC
```

Complete Query below:

```
SELECT tracks.track_title,track_rank.track_id, COUNT(track_rank.track_id) AS  number_of_repetitions 
FROM tracks,track_rank 
WHERE track_rank.track_position = 1 AND track_rank.track_date_entered 
BETWEEN '1970-01-01' AND '1972-12-31' 
AND tracks.track_id = track_rank.track_id 
GROUP BY track_rank.track_id 
ORDER BY COUNT(track_rank.track_id) DESC;
```

Comment: That gives me same result, I want select songs with maximum number of repetitions from the result after executing the above query. There are 4 songs with highest number of repetitions along with other 57 songs. I want to select only those 4 songs. Any suggestion for that??